# phpmailer DATA NOT ACCEPTED FROM THE SERVER FOR ATTACHMENT IN CENTOS

Tags: php, centos, phpmailer

This might be a silly question but I've been looking for an answer for a week....

The PHPmailer attachment is working completely fine in my localsystem and also in my server (Centos).  But my problem is, one particular .doc file is not attached to the mail hence the recipient is not getting an email.

That particular .doc file is uploading in my localsystem (WAMP) and email with attachment is also working. But it is not working in my server.

NOTE:  Even other .doc files are uploading and attached properly in my local and server.

Comment: Might it be related to the file size of that particular document? If so, check the max upload filesize in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You Just Need To Update Your PHP Mailer Pages With Latest Versions..

Comment: Can you elaborate further about this? Is this a known bug fixed by now?